# Ceate a yes/no dialog box to verify user entries

Tags: bash, dialog

I am writing a bash script that prompts for for several user entries prior to the start of the script. I am looking for the best way to use dialog to have the users verify the information. I am trying to modify the example below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# dynbox.sh - Yes/No box demo
dialog --title "Delete file" \
--backtitle "Linux Shell Script Tutorial Example" \
--yesno "Are you sure you want to permanently delete \"/tmp/foo.txt\"?" 7 60

# Get exit status
# 0 means user hit [yes] button.
# 1 means user hit [no] button.
# 255 means user hit [Esc] key.
response=$?
case $response in
0) echo "File deleted.";;
1) echo "File not deleted.";;
255) echo "[ESC] key pressed.";;
esac
```

I am running it to some errors though when trying to create it. Basically I want a yes/no dialog box to say

```
Please verify your entered information:
Install SSL : $InstallSSL
Domain Name : $DomainName
etc
```

the left side will be static text where the right will display the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include newlines in a double quoted string which also expands variables:

```
dialog --title "Verification" \
--yesno "Please verify your entered information:
Install SSL : $InstallSSL
Domain Name : $DomainName" 7 60
```

Comment: Ahh thank you. i was getting to happy with the quotes and was trying to do

    "Install SSL : $InstallSSL" \

On each line

Comment: If you don't like the multiline text, use `"one line"$'\n'"second line"`